# Adobe Flash AS 3.0 - response action delay

Tags: flash

I'm having some issues with my flying penguin game. The penguin has to fall down when no control key is being pressed. But to go up, you'll have to press spacebar, when you press spacebar, the pinguin goes up but it has some delay before it goes up.

I can't figure out why.. I could use some help/suggestions

Example of the problem: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1402729638 (press space to go up)

Code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vallen);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, vliegen);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, loslaten);

var penguin:MovieClip = penguin_mc;
var snelheid:int = 1;
var versnelling:int = 1;
var ingedrukt:Boolean = false;


function vallen(evt:Event):void {

    if(penguin.y < 350 && ingedrukt == false){

        penguin.y += snelheid + versnelling;
        versnelling++;

        if(penguin.rotation < 50){

            penguin.rotation += 15;

        }

    }

}

function vliegen (evt:Event):void {
    ingedrukt = true;

    if(penguin.y > 50) {
        penguin.y -= 10;

        if(penguin.rotation > -20){

            penguin.rotation -= 15;

        }

    }
    penguin.play();
}

function loslaten(evt:Event){
    ingedrukt = false;
    snelheid = 1;
    versnelling = 1;
    penguin.gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Kind regards,
Flint

Comment: try to put the conditional in bracket ie `(penguin.y < 350) && (ingedrukt == false)` maybe that'll solve it